# What is the difference between Association and Composition Aggregation in Autosar domain

Tags: c, uml, software-design, autosar, automotive

I am reading Autosar document and in one of the document (Autosar_TemplateModelingGuideline.pdf), it says that:

> Composite aggregation, forming a whole-part relationship
>
> Regular association, expressing a reference from the associating to
> the associated model element

My question is: what is the difference between these two in practice? How do I have to interpret them in a class diagram, e.g.  the `Com Module` in Autosar.:

[The AUTOSAR COM module’s Configuration Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnZXH.png)

Consider Specified class `ComGwSignalRef` surrounded with a red rectangle. This class has a composition relation with `ComGwSignalRef` class and two regular association with `ComGroupSignal` and `ComSignal`.

How would  you interpret this as a developer and how do you implement in C?

1. if regular association is a reference to an object that has independent life from `ComGwSignalRef` why designer do not use `instanceRef` here?
2. if it is not a reference, why did the designer not use composition?

PS. There is a concept in Autosar "InstanceRef" which is used for reference for independent object with independent lifecycle.

Comment: Somewhat simplified: Composition - `struct F { struct SomeOtherStruct x; };` Association - `struct F { struct SomeOtherStruct *x; };` In the composition case `x` is a part of the object created from the structure `F`. In the association case `x` references another object, but it's not part of objects created from `F`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude in the same document it says "In general it is pure modeling taste whether an aggregation is shown as class attribute or explicit association" and "Metaclasses defined within the same M2 model MUST be aggregated in form of explicit associations and aggregations" which I interpret that associations (regular and compsition) are some kind of attribute but since they are not primitive(i.e int, float) we use association to model them which means that they are part of class.

Comment: @Ister I already studied it but that was not my answer or too vague for Autosar domain. What I found from all is that Associations(either regular or composition) lifecycle is dependent of associating class but there is a tiny difference between them.
in Autosar, composition is used in a module, if the module is determining the structure of associated class and regular is used, if the structure of associated class determined by another module other than associating module

Comment: for more explanation, in composition associating is complete control over associated class including structure of associated class and make an object inside itself but in case of regular association, the associating class must know about the structure of associated class(does not have control over structure) and make an object inside itself

Comment: Maybe you should have made the title more clear with your intention. UML has only one definition, so maybe Autosar is doing something bad?

Comment: @qwerty_so Well Autosar is a profile on UML 2, I mentioned Autosar in Title and also I tagged Autosar, Also I explained Autosar point of view about association. If you have something to add which can improve the idea I am happy to hear.

Comment: I think this question is not a full duplicate : it is very specific to the autosar profile, which for example prohibits the use of shared aggregation if I understood well.  Moreover it asks the question in the context of links by reference.  I therefore propose to reopen it.

Comment: For the record: an InstanceRef is NOT „used for reference for independent object with independent lifecycle“. An InstanceRef represents a ordered bundle of references that identify contexts (created by utilizing the type-prototype pattern in the AUTOSAR meta-model) in the concrete model structure and finally one reference to the target element.

Comment: Maybe I was to quick with closing. So I reopened your question. I now remember that there's a profile with that name but it was never in my focus. And the diagram really looks broken (see comment on Jens' answer).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should also consider the following:

The `Com Configuration` is an instance of the EcuC configuration meta-model as defined in the `AUTOSAR_TPS_EcuConfiguration`.

The `ComGwSignalRef` is of type `EcucChoiceContainerDef`, and as such, the two `destination` associations of `ComSignal` and `ComGroupSignal` have a meaning. Only one of these "choices" can be selected in the final configuration as a reference. In AUTOSAR metamodel, that is the definition of how `EcucChoiceContainerDef` works, in UML you might need here an additional `constraint` element to define the XOR relation of two associations.

Answer (score 0):

An object can only be composed as part of **one** object.

```
A <>- C -<>B
```

In the diagram above `C` is composed in `A` and `B`. This would lead to the following instances:

```
a: A <>- c: C -<> b:B
```

Now the *specific instance* `c` is now part of both `a` *and* `b`.

What happen would with `c` if `b` goes out of scope? By the semantics it should be destroyed *and* not be destroyed (`a` still exists).

Or more pointed:
Take Alice,Bob, and Collar Bone as examples. Alice’s collar bone cannot be part of Bob.

UML is a modeling language and has not the same expressiveness as, say a C compiler. This is by design to simplify things.

Remember: *All models are wrong, but some are useful*. — George E. P. Box

Comment: when dealing with Associations(including regular, shared composition and strict composition) we are dealing with objects and and we should interpret in a way that concepts shown in class diagram make sense. in your case I interpret that there are two distinct object of a1 and a2 one is part of A and the other is part of B. but I can not understand what do you mean by this answer to my question

Comment: Where in the diagram did you see such a double-composite aggregation?

Comment: I did not see it, but question (2) was „why is there no composition used“ and this is the answer. Com Group signal is already owned by another class.

Comment: Found it: bottom right to the config via two paths so the config is composite to two objects which is wrong.

Comment: @qwerty_so, it is not wrong. It would be wrong if the multiplicities were `1`, but in the diagram, the multiplicities are not specified, so they might as well be `0..1`. Take `A <>- C -<>B`. This can lead to instances `a:A <>- c1:C` and `b:B <>- c2:C`.

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl You are right I always get fooled by such constructs :-(